# Read data from NetworkStream without heavy loop

Tags: c#, .net, select, tcp

I'm reading data from a TcpClient/NetworkStream in a loop that looks like this:

```
while (true)
{
    byte[] answer = new byte[1000];
    int count = m_networkStream.Read(answer, 0, 1000);
    if (count > 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The bad thing is that the `Read()` returns immediately 0 when no data is available. The wrapping `TcpClient` does not have a `Select()` method or similar that would stop until some data arrives. So I have a tight loop eating up huge amounts of CPU time.

So... how can this be done better? Is there a way to *suspend* the thread until data arrives or is there a `Read()` method that blocks?

Thanks!

To Editors: this is NOT a duplicate to the other, linked question! When you would not have edited (or better: damaged) my original question you would have been able to see this. The reason for the other question is a permanent loop for "data available", here reading of the data does not block/I'm looking for a method to do a select() on the socket.

Comment: Are you *certain* it's returning 0 even when the stream isn't closed? I'd expect it to block until either some data is available or the stream has been closed at the other end. (And if it's been closed, you shouldn't loop back and try to read again.) That's how all streams work. I strongly suspect you're just seeing a closed stream...

Comment: If you really *are* seeing this behaviour, please show a short but complete program which demonstrates it. Just setting up a server which accepts the connection but doesn't write any data to it would be enough from the server side... and a simple client pretty much just containing the loop would show the client issue.

Comment: *Heavy* loops are ok (most of software are just loops), unless they are using 100% CPU. Insert `Thread.Sleep(0);` somewhere and you should be fine.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: yes, it is returning also when no data are available, this is conform to the documentation which describes exactly this behaviour: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Elmi: I think that's just poorly worded documentation, personally - this is something I've *never* seen and it would violate the contract of Stream.Read: "Read returns 0 only when there is no more data in the stream and no more is expected (such as a closed socket or end of file)." That's why I've asked for a short but complete program to reproduce the issue - do you have one yet?

Answer (score 0):

Use asynchronously read method of NetworkStream

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not what I'm looking for - my problem is not that I want to do something different in the meantime but that I want to block the whole thing until data are available. So I'm looking for some kind of select().